# How to plot data from multiple variables inside a single netCDF file with python

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf4, spectra

I'm new to handling netCDF data with Python (and a programming beginner) so sorry if I'm unclear.

I have a nc file that contains several variables and I need to access the value of each variable for the same pixel and plot.

These are the variables inside my nc file:

odict_keys(['lon', 'lat', 'l2_flags', 'spm_nechad', 't_nechad', 't_dogliotti', 'chl_oc3', 'chl_re_gons740', 'chl_re_moses3b740', 'chl_re_mishra', 'Rrs_443', 'Rrs_492', 'Rrs_560', 'Rrs_665', 'Rrs_704', 'Rrs_740', 'Rrs_783', 'Rrs_833', 'Rrs_865', 'Rrs_1614', 'Rrs_2202', 'rhow_443', 'rhow_492', 'rhow_560', 'rhow_665', 'rhow_704', 'rhow_740', 'rhow_783', 'rhow_833', 'rhow_865', 'rhow_1614', 'rhow_2202'])

Basically what I need to do is to plot a spectra with wavelengths between 443nm and 865nm. Each wavelength is contained inside a variable with the name 'rhow_ (in X I will have the wavelength and in Y the corresponding reflectance value) for a single pixel. However, each value is stored in a different variable (rhow_<wavelength) and I need to extract the values corresponding on the same pixel from each variable.

This is what I've been trying so far:

```
fn = 'mypath/file.nc'  
ds = nc.Dataset(fn)  

print(ds.variables.keys())  
wavelenghts = [443, 492, 560, 665, 704, 740, 783, 865]  

lons = ds.variables['lon'][:]  
lats = ds.variables['lat'][:]  
rhow_443 = ds.variables['rhow_443'][-8.929999, 38.486744]   
rhow_492 = ds.variables['rhow_492'][-8.929999, 38.486744]  
rhow_560 = ds.variables['rhow_560'][-8.929999, 38.486744]  #coordinates of AS_7  
rhow_665 = ds.variables['rhow_665'][-8.929999, 38.486744]  
rhow_705 = ds.variables['rhow_704'][-8.929999, 38.486744]  
rhow_740 = ds.variables['rhow_740'][-8.929999, 38.486744]  
rhow_783 = ds.variables['rhow_783'][-8.929999, 38.486744]  
rhow_865 = ds.variables['rhow_865'][-8.929999, 38.486744]
```

How can I plot the values to produce a spectra?
I hope I made my self clear. Cheers!

Comment: Strongly suggest xarray to read netcdf files: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with my package ncplot (install using pip). This should work:

```
import ncplot 

ncplot.view("mypath/file.nc")
```

This will generate an interactive plot for all variables in your file, so long as the netcdf file is close to cf compliant.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but this is not working for me since I don't want to plot all the variables.

Comment: In that case, can you please revise your question, as it is not particularly clear.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. On the question, I left the list of all the variables that are contained in my .nc file. However, I don't need to plot them all but just the ones which names start with "rhow_".